# thread polling jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter rollbacks transaction but MQ Message is sent

Tags: spring-integration

I am polling **50 DB records** using *jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter* as *transactional*. That means all **50 records** will be processed in **one (same) transaction**. And I want them to be processed in one same transaction.

In the sample code, *ProcessIndividualRecord::updateDB()* updates the status in the DB and after that *notificationJMSChannel* sends the message to MQ.

If there is an exception happens in *updateDB method* while processing **50th record** then framework rollbacks all the previously updated **49 records** and control goes to *ProcessorExceptionHandler* with the **50th record**.

My challenge is "*notificationJMSChannel*" already sent previous *49 records* to MQ.

How can I rollback those?

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="initial.poller"
    query="${poller.get}"
    update="${poller.update}"
    max-rows="${poller.maxRow:50}"
    row-mapper="pollerRowMapper"
    data-source="dataSource" channel="deliveryContactTypeChannel">
        <int:transactional/>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="deliveryContactTypeChannel" />

<int:splitter id="splitDeliveryContactType"
    ref="deliveryContactTypeMessageProcessor" method="handleJdbcMessage"
    input-channel="deliveryContactTypeChannel"
    output-channel="processIndividualRecordChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="statusUpdate"
    input-channel="processIndividualRecordChannel"
    output-channel="notificationJMSChannel"
    ref="processIndividualRecord" method="updateDB" />

<!-- send MQ message -->
<int:channel id="notificationJMSChannel"></int:channel>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="jmsOut" channel="notificationJMSChannel" 
    destination="senderTopic" jms-template="jmsQueueTemplate">
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- Error handling -->
<int:channel id="jmsErrorChannel" />

<int:header-enricher id="errorMsg.HeaderEnricher"
    input-channel="errorChannel"
    output-channel="jmsErrorChannel">
    <int:header name="failpayload" expression="payload.failedMessage" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:service-activator
    input-channel="jmsErrorChannel" method="handleException">
    <bean class="com.digital.alerts.integration.ProcessorExceptionHandler" />
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider to use `JtaTransactionManager` if you deal with JEE container, or *chain* DataSource and JMS transaction managers: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html.

See `ChainedTransactionManager` implementation ins Spring Data:

```
/**
 * {@link PlatformTransactionManager} implementation that orchestrates transaction creation, commits and rollbacks to a
 * list of delegates. Using this implementation assumes that errors causing a transaction rollback will usually happen
 * before the transaction completion or during the commit of the most inner {@link PlatformTransactionManager}.
 * <p />
 * The configured instances will start transactions in the order given and commit/rollback in <em>reverse</em> order,
 * which means the {@link PlatformTransactionManager} most likely to break the transaction should be the <em>last</em>
 * in the list configured. A {@link PlatformTransactionManager} throwing an exception during commit will automatically
 * cause the remaining transaction managers to roll back instead of committing.
 *
 * @author Michael Hunger
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 * @since 1.6
 */
public class ChainedTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager {
```

Right now it looks like every single message is sent in its own JMS local transaction. And this fully doesn't know that your have an outer JDBC transaction.